# Apache fastcgi: is there a means to dynamically check an ENV value at subroutine use?

Tags: apache, perl, internationalization, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I apologize if the problem definition is a bit disjointed.  We have been attacking this issue on many different vectors.

Basic description, we have a website we are trying to provide translations for using Locale::TextDomain

We have fastcgi scripts, that call our local library of perl modules.   Fastcgi and translation is tricky (as we are using it) because the language is set at the launch of the script and persists.

So in our library of perl modules this works.

```
package SR::Locale;
our $LOCALE_NAMESPACE = 'es';
use Locale::TextDomain::UTF8 qw( $LOCALE_NAMESPACE );
our $word = __("football");
```

But we can't figure out a means to dynamically set the variable $LOCALE_NAMESPACE at startup.  We'd like to set it based on the request_uri or the dir path of the script being executed or something like that.  So we'd like to do something like, but we can't figure this out in a fast cgi setting:

```
package SR::Locale;
$ENV{REQUEST_URI} =~ m{example.com/(..)/}
our $LOCALE_NAMESPACE = $1;
use Locale::TextDomain::UTF8 qw( $LOCALE_NAMESPACE );
our $word = __("football");
```

in this example (for a fastcgi), $ENV{REQUEST_URI} is blank in the module at script start.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I have not been able to find any references to translation and fastcgi working together in perl.

Comment: What's with all the `our` instead of `my`???

Comment: @ikegami Guessing he'd like to be able to change its value from another Perl file in his program...

Comment: @Marcus (1) wouldn't work just so. making it `our` doesn't make it magically leap out of its own file (2) don't want to do that. that's what (programming) _interfaces_ are for, so that things can be changed in a clear, articulate, and structured way.

Comment: @Marcus, When? Before loading the module? Useless because the outside value would get clobbered by the assignment. After loading the module? Useless because the value has already been used by then. It just wouldn't work. (It would also form high [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)), which is a bad thing..)

Comment: @ikegami Was simply commenting on why people use 'our', to share the variable across packages.  Not commenting on how advisable in any context, especially since we aren't seeing the code of its other usage.

Comment: @Marcus, hmmm, That's not what you said at all. You gave a reason for the OP doing it that made no sense.

Comment: @ikegami Well, I said to he might want to change its value from another Perl file in his program, or otherwise access it, not limit its scope to this package.  That's the use of 'our'.  Regardless, we're not helping his question by debating this lol.

Comment: @Marcus, Re "*I said to he might want to change its value from another Perl file in his program*", And I explained why that won't work.

Comment: @ikegami I'm sure we just misunderstand each other, as 'our' works fine for me.  Perhaps I am describing the behavior poorly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185150/discussion-between-marcus-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 4):

One clear problem is that the runtime assignment to `$LOCALE_NAMESPACE`, that uses the capture from regex on `$ENV{REQUEST_URI}`, runs *after* the `use` statement where that variable is used, since all [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statements run at compile time.

If the sole problem is of how to set `$LOCALE_NAMESPACE` in time for `use`, do it in `BEGIN` phase

```
package SR::Locale;

my $LOCALE_NAMESPACE;

BEGIN { 
    # Add a check that $ENV{REQUEST_URI} is indeed set by the environment
    ($LOCALE_NAMESPACE) = $ENV{REQUEST_URI} =~ m{example.com/(..)/};
}

use Locale::TextDomain::UTF8 qw( $LOCALE_NAMESPACE );
```

Don't forget that this `BEGIN` must come before `use` statements that rely on it. All code that runs in `BEGIN` phase is executed in order of its appearance in source files (including any further `use` statements or `BEGIN` blocks inside the `use`d modules).

Comment: unfortunately, this won't fix the issue with fastcgi as that env is still not set in that case.

Comment: @Sean The `%ENV` carries values set by the environment as the script is started. Are you saying that the environment _is not_ at all (yet?) set at that time? (Is this something inherent to fastcgi?)

Comment: I think that this is a fastcgi issue.

Comment: @Sean Alright, it may be so (if the environment doesn't get set at all by the time the script starts).  But note that one problem with shown code is that the `use` goes at compile time, so before any and all runtime statements (regardless of whether they come before it in the source).  So the `use` that needs that `$ENV{...}` runs _before_ that variable is set.  (I edited the answer to clearly state that.)

Comment: @Sean Can you confirm whether you get _any_ environment set? For instance, right at the top of the module file add `say "$_ => $ENV{$_}" for keys %ENV;` (or some such)?  (You need `use feature 'say';` before this, or an equivalent like `use v5.10` or newer, to turn on features. Or of course just `print` with manual newlines. Once we are it: add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to the top of the module. They don't cascade down from the caller.)

Comment: We've moved onto another solution.  If I remember where we ended up on this path there just didn't seem to be a way to get the ENV vars within the fastcgi loop, but if I'm wrong, in my defense it's been a good whiles since we looked at this.

Comment: @Sean OK, thanks for update.  One thing to remember from this Q though: since `use` goes at compile time it can't make use of any runtime statements, variables, etc (even if they come before it in source).  So if a `use` statement needs a constant, which much be retrieved from somewhere first, that constant must be worked out in a `BEGIN` block (and before that `use`).   This is what's going on in the question as asked here, and is a legitimate and good question on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that much about translation in fastcgi environments, but I do know that `use` is a compile-time statement, so the `use` statement in your script would be the first thing that Perl would execute (even before `$LOCALE_NAMESPACE` is initialized).

The run-time equivalent of `use MODULE ARGS` is

```
require MODULE;
MODULE->import(ARGS);
```

This works sometimes to dynamically configure a module at run-time, though it also has many failure modes.